# Automated spell and grammar hints to support good content and proofreading

Tags: feature-request, spelling

While quite a lot of volunteer work is given on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites for proofreading, why isn't there an automated support to write and proof read from the site?

My arguments for this are:

- The communities will grow and readers/posters may outnumber reviewers/editors by orders of magnitude
- There are user experience success stories like [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) and open source software components like  [languagetool](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool) (used in OpenOffice).
- If you tell me, why not use for myself the free grammarly browser plugin, or even [languagetool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/languagetool/?src=featured), I tell you that I do not want to exchange text content data from my browser this way with third party.

Comment: Run a local instance of languagetool. Problem solved.

Comment: *I tell you that I do not want to exchange text content data from my browser this way with third party.* I'd think the most likely thing they'd do to implement this is to use something 3rd party anyway. Why would they bother writing something from scratch?

Comment: @NathanTuggy this is what I am thinking of but not sure how to integrate with the Firefox plugin (offtopic here)

Comment: I really don't want Stack Overflow telling me that I'm spelling words like behaviour and colour incorrectly because I'm not.

Comment: @J.Doe: I would assume you could just run the GUI it appears to provide, then copy-and-paste in there?

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy - would do; though specifically with languagetool I've find the following: https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/issues/1214 so maybe it's not good enough :-/

Comment: So...you don't want to exchange text content data with a third party, even with an embedded tool, but you're willing to post it publicly on one of the most popular programming sites there is?  I'm not seeing what the actual problem is.  Privacy?

Answer (score 10):

I disagree.  It's not Stack Overflow's place to add automated proofreading tools to its site.  It's the reviewer's/poster's/editor's responsibility to ensure that they are clear, concise and using appropriate English constructs.

Someone who can proofread without the need for those tools can always come along and make the necessary corrections, too.

Also...not sure if you weren't already aware of this, but posters already outnumber editors by several orders of magnitude.  There's more posts than there are edits to those posts, easily.

Comment: so it is inevitable that quality of content will decrease over time I suppose

Comment: @J.Doe: Are you saying that, without automatic spelling/grammar checking tools, people will naturally stop using proper spelling/grammar? If that's the case, how did we ever *develop* spelling and grammar to begin with? We managed to have decent spelling/grammar for hundreds of years without automatic tools.

Comment: sure that, but as I am not a native English speaker, these automatic tools have been *invaluable* to me. And still are.. Same way I improved my coding skills thanks to Eclipse. Do not understand the argument that automatic tools somehow make having advanced skills less important. I think it's about helping those who are more at the beginning!

Comment: @J.Doe but why does stack has to do it? Open a Google doc, write your question in it, c&p, problem fixed! Why should Stack use development time on something with such an easy workaround?

Comment: @Patrice to guard content quality, it would be a nice option and I think there is not too much development effort. Surely I admin there are more important features but hey this is a feature request! (very much downvoted now)

Comment: @J.Doe I get your point. But my point of view there doesn't change: the problem you perceive is so easy to work around that I think having it is overkill.

Comment: This might be an overkill, but hard to judge that without numbers. Would be interesting to track - easiest way I can think of - number of posts which never get edited against growing number of posters. This would illustrate growing probability of errors.

Comment: I think it'd be more interesting to track how many questions need editing for spelling and grammar after posting.  If askers truly care about asking the best question they can, then adding a spellcheck themselves prior to posting will do a very good job towards showing effort.

Comment: @J.Doe Number of edits to a post doesn't correlate with how correct the spelling and grammar is of that post.  Lots of people post perfectly correct posts from the start.  Lots of people have terrible posts even after 10 edits.

Comment: @Servy this assumes on the long end that 10x more random users are not likely to generate declining content quality.

Comment: @J.Doe No, it doesn't.  It's merely the statement that the number of edits has no correlation to post quality.  The fact that those two things aren't correlated doesn't tell you anything about the quality of the content based on the size of the userbase.

Comment: @Servy for sure taking random probes allows for more certainty.